# Error while creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create and add a new column as Week to dataframe. Also, I am doing this based on if else condition. I am using code below.

```
 # List of the conditions
conditions = [
    (df_sup[(df_sup['Date']>='2016-11-14') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-11-21')]),
    (df_sup[(df_sup['Date']>='2016-11-21') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-11-28')]), 
    (df_sup[(df_sup['Date']>='2016-11-28') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-12-05')]), 
    (df_sup[(df_sup['Date']>='2016-12-05') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-12-12')]),
    (df_sup[(df_sup['Date']>='2016-12-12') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-12-19')])
]


# list of the values I want to assign for each condition
values = ['week1','week2','week3','week4','week5']

# Let's create a new column and use np.select to assign values to it using our lists as arguments
df_sup['Week'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

But, I got below error. How can I fix it?

[image]

Also, I share data below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data `conditions` are not list of conditions, because is used [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), so get list of DataFrames.

So for list of conditions remove `df_sup[` and last `]`:

```
conditions = [
    (df_sup['Date']>='2016-11-14') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-11-21'),
    (df_sup['Date']>='2016-11-21') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-11-28'), 
    (df_sup['Date']>='2016-11-28') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-12-05'), 
    (df_sup['Date']>='2016-12-05') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-12-12'),
    (df_sup['Date']>='2016-12-12') & (df_sup['Date']<'2016-12-19')
]
```